# Can't resolve a function from a process module (user32.dll): "Couldn't resolve error at '<module>!<function>'"

Tags: debuggers, windbg

I have a WinForm project in C++.
I attached a kernel debugger to my VMware machine.
I set a breakpoint on the kernel and switched context to my application:

```
0: kd> !process 0 0 WindowsProject1.exe
PROCESS ffffcf07bad91080
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 22c8    Peb: dd35f3e000  ParentCid: 1598
    DirBase: 1b9b83000  ObjectTable: ffffe5829cb59b00  HandleCount: 145.
    Image: WindowsProject1.exe  
0: kd> .process ffffcf07bad91080
Implicit process is now ffffcf07`bad91080
WARNING: .cache forcedecodeuser is not enabled
```

I also understand that I can do it like that:

```
0: kd> dx -s Debugger.Sessions[0].Processes[8904].SwitchTo()
```

Anyway, I want to find the `SetWindowTextW` function and set a breakpoint on that.
I tried to find it in the process context:

```
0: kd> dd user32!SetWindowTextW
Couldn't resolve error at 'user32!SetWindowTextW'
```

Why it doesn't find it?

Comment: use process specific breakpoint like bu /p ffffcf07bad91080 user32!SetWindowTextA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I ran:

```
0: kd> .symfix C:\debug\symbols
*** Unable to resolve unqualified symbol in Bp expression 'user32.SetWindowTextW'.
*** Unable to resolve unqualified symbol in Bp expression 'user32.SetWindowTextW'.
0: kd> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts on
0: kd> .reload /f
```

Now I was able to use it:

```
0: kd> dd user32!SetWindowTextW
00007ffc`243c1cb0  245c8948 83485708 8b4830ec 108ae8fa
00007ffc`243c1cc0  8b480000 c08548d8 8b483c74 035ae8c8
```

Comment: Hehe, a classic among kernel mode devs.